# Laravel 5: Querying a many to many relationship without "pivot" in the result

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the following tables

- users

  - id
- books

  - id
- favourite_books

  - id
  - user_id (FK)
  - book_id (FK)

I have the following Model:

```
class User {
    public function favouriteBooks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class, 'favourite_books');
    }
}
```

I want to get all the ids that belong to a user.

The way I am doing this currently is like so:

```
$user->favouriteBooks()->select('book_id')->get();
```

However this returns data like so;

```
[
   {
     "book_id": 23,
     "pivot": {
       "user_id": 57,
       "book_id": 23
     }
   },
   {
     "book_id": 41,
     "pivot": {
       "user_id": 57,
       "book_id": 41
     }
   },
   ...
]
```

I want it to return data like so:

```
[
   23,
   41,
   ...
]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `pluck()` method:

```
$user->favouriteBooks()->pluck('book_id');
```

Comment: Awesome. I recommend keeping the `->select('book_id')` though as that's less data travelling from the database to the server

Comment: Not sure who did that or why

Comment: Why? What does it do? Please add details to your answer.

Answer (score 25):

I recommend putting pivot in the hidden array like in user.php:

```
protected $hidden = ['pivot'];
```

which would remove pivot from all json's returned.

Comment: It's ok for a tiny app, but what if you'll need to include pivot data in one query? You'll need to rebuild all other queries to hide pivot data and test every one of them?

Comment: I think you are right, maybe the best practice is to use a transformer and not include the pivot when not needed

Comment: @HazemEmad thank you for answer, but please fix the place of the dollar sign. It should be before "hidden", not before "protected".

Comment: Thanks for the notice

Comment: It only worked for me when i added it in the Books class. I am call User->favouriteBooks

Answer (score -1):

Or :

```
$user = User::where('id',1)->with('favourite_books')->first();
$fbs = [];
foreach($user->favourite_books as $book) {
    $fbs[] = $book['book_id'];
}
unset($user->favourite_books);
$user->favourite_books = $fbs;

return $user;
```